# Regex doesn't work as expected

Tags: c, regex

I am trying to match a valid nickname in C.

I have the following function:

```
int check_valid_nickname(char *nick) {
    if(!match(nick,NICK_PATTERN)) {
        return 0;
    } else {
}

int match(char *str, char *pattern) {
    int    status;
    regex_t re;
    if (regcomp(&re, pattern, REG_EXTENDED|REG_NOSUB) != 0) {
        /* Report error. */
        return 0;
    }
    status = regexec(&re, str, (size_t) 0, NULL, 0);
    regfree(&re);
    if (status != 0) {
        /* Report error. */
        return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

and NICK_PATTERN is defined as

```
#define NICK_PATTERN "/^[a-z0-9_\\|\\{\\}\\[\\]\\^]{4,36}$/i"
```

I have tested the pattern on regexr and it matches perfectly the way I need it.

However, my function in C is still always returning 0. Am I overlooking something? Thanks for any pointers.

Comment: This is a wild guess, but I have a feeling you need more backslashes, perhaps as much as twice as many. The preprocessor is probably not replacing NICK_PATTERN with what you think it is.

Comment: `printf(NICK_PATTERN)` and then run the result through regexr and see if it still runs as expected. If it still does you'll have to provide more information on which regex library you are using.

Comment: This crossed my mind, but since the proper escape for the blackslash in C is \\ this should be correct. I printed out the pattern to be safe, and it comes out correctly.

Addition: Just tried it again to be safe. Result is correct in regexr.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regex you're looking for is

```
#define NICK_PATTERN "^[]a-z0-9|{}^[]{4,36}$"
```

and you want to compile it like so:

```
regcomp(&re, pattern, REG_ICASE | REG_EXTENDED | REG_NOSUB)
```

`regcomp`, `regexec` etc. use the POSIX regular expression syntax, which means slightly different escaping rules, no slashes for matching, and no flags like in Perl -- these are replaced, in a manner of speaking, by the functions and their flags. There's a rundown of POSIX syntax [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/syntax/basic_extended.html). It is written for a C++ interface, but the rules are the same.

Differences from what you expected in this particular case: You don't have to escape in a `[]` set, and if there's a `]` to be part of the set, it has to come at the front.

Comment: This did the trick, thanks, I'll lookup the POSIX syntax, since I'd like to learn something. Thanks a lot for your input, appreciate it :)